# What exactly happens when adding a Blank after a built-in function used in the rules of ReplaceAll?

Tags: replacement

Well, this question is just for curiosity, personally I never use `ReplaceAll` like this:

```
Cos[2 x] /. Sin_[2 x_] -> 2 Sin[x] Cos[x]
(* => 2 Cos[x]^2 *)
```

How to explain the result?

Comment: As a starting point towards understanding what's happening (in addition to Rojo's explanation): ponder on why `MatchQ[Cos[2 x], Sin_[2 x_]]` returns the result it indeed returns... also, consider the similarities between what you have and the following snippet: `Cos[2 x] /. f_[2 x_] -> 2 f[x] Cos[x]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple, but you made it look confusing because of your naming

`Cos[2 x]` matches this pattern, `_[2 _]`

Now, you name the head `Sin` (bad practice :P), and the internal blank, `x` and transform that to `2 "the head"["the argument"] Cos["the argument"]`. In this case, the head is `Cos` so the result becomes `2 Cos[x] Cos[x]` which is `2 Cos[x]^2`

Comment: You've been using reverse ticks all day... Something messed up in your keyboard settings?

Comment: @rm-rf yeah, I'm trying out W8 and couldn't get it to take my custom keyboard layout. And it seems the layout I'm using has the opposite tick on the same key...